# Best way to create and host a python webapp that takes user input and adds it to sql databases?

Tags: python, html, sql, flask, web-applications

I'm currently working on a project to make data entry easier for myself,
I have sql tables set up in an azure database, and i can write python code that adds data to them easily enough,

but what i want to do next is to have a webapp that users can login to, to do their data entry,
so when you login, your user and password will be checked against a sql table,
and then if correct you will move onto a data entry page where it will show you the fields you need to enter and then once submitted, these will be added to the sql table,

so far, i have tried coming up with the python code and the html for the site, and getting them to work together using Flask but i am not sure if this is the best way to do it and my main concern is i dont know how to host this code anywhere other than on my local device,

Thanks for your time! this problem is really bugging me as i'm confident i can alter and add to sql tables however i need to, i'm just trying to figure out the best way to make this a usable app for other people,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Flask is a good solution for what you're going to do. Even if there are many other possibilities.

Once your app is ready. You can make it available for others from your computer.
Or you can host it on a server.

In really short you have to :

- get a Serveur
- get a domain name
- install a database
- upload your project (with the new database configuration)
- Run the project

Here are some links, where you can read more on it

- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-web-application-using-flask-and-deploy-it-to-the-cloud-3551c985e492/
- https://www.linode.com/docs/development/python/flask-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu/